# Openshift - Edit mongodb.config

Tags: mongodb, configuration, openshift

I installed a mongodb gear to my Openshift application.
I am now trying to update the configuration file in /etc/mongodb.config.
Unfortunately the file is in read-only mode.

Did one of you experience the same ? Is there a workaround to it ?

Comment: I never needed to edit that file. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to change configurations as storage.smallFiles to true. My main problem is that the mongodb cartridge is taking quickly the 1GB allocated to it. I suspect the journal files and pre-allocation to take most of that place.